# How to get the NodeValue from <td> type input

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using this HTML and I am trying to parse it to get the `nodeValue` of all the elements in the table columns.

```
<table id="custinfo">
    <tr>
        <td><label>First Name</label></td> 
        <td><input type="text" name="firstname" ></td>    
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td><label>Last Name</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lastname" ></td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Phone Number</label></td> 
        <td><input type="text" name="email" ></td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

Here is the PHP It's only working for the labels but not for the input types.

```
$Dom= new DOMDocument();   
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$Dom->loadHTMLFile('Pre_order.html'); 
$info=$Dom->getElementById('custinfo');
$inforows=$info->getElementsByTagName("tr");
$input_tags = $Dom->getElementsByTagName('input'); 
$fnamecol=$inforows->item(0)->getElementsByTagName("td");
$fname=$fnamecol->item(1)->nodeValue; //this is returning null Instead of returning the input text value.
```

Comment: Try $input_tags->item(1)->nodeValue;

Comment: This looks clumsy. Try using [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) instead.

Comment: @shashi tried Input_tags but its still returning null

Comment: @Raptor thanks, I will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After actually adding values to the input elements, try the following

```
$input_tags->item(1)->getAttribute('value')
```

(Btw, check the case of `$Dom` and `$dom` in your examples.)

Here's some sample code that works when executed at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ :

```
<?php

$htmlString = <<<HTML
<table id="custinfo">
    <tr>
        <td><label>First Name</label></td> 
        <td><input type="text" name="firstname" value="Jane"></td>    
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td><label>Last Name</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lastname" value="Doe"></td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Phone Number</label></td> 
        <td><input type="text" name="email" value="212-555-1212"></td>
    </tr>   
</table>
HTML;

$dom= new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($htmlString); 
$input_tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('input'); 

echo $input_tags->item(1)->getAttribute('value'); // "Doe"
```

Comment: Please see my edited post for a sample that works (noting that I added values to the inputs) and can be confirmed at the PHP sandbox I linked to.

Comment: I am trying to concatenate it to a string object. That may be why it's not working

Comment: Concatenate it or convert it? What is the code that is not working for you (based on the above)?

Comment: I have a string caled $orders=" "; and I want to add  $input_tags->item(1)->getAttribute('value'); to the string

Comment: It works if I already set the value but I want to get it from a value set when a text is put into a textbox.

Comment: If you're talking about getting the text value out of the DOM when the user enters it, you need JavaScript for getting the `value` property on the input and send whatever you need back to the server. Either that or you need to surround your HTML with a ` <form>` element and have PHP pick up `$_GET['lastname']` , etc. when the user submits the form. But if that is the case, that is all beyond the scope of this question you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple_dom_parser.php library instead (Download library: https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/ & docs: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
require_once('simple_dom_parser.php');

// Create DOM from file
$html = file_get_html('Pre_order.html');


// Find all labels
foreach($html->find('label') as $label)
       echo $label->plaintext . '<br>';


// Find all inputs
foreach($html->find('input') as $input)
       echo $input->name . '<br>';
```

Comment: it's giving me this errora:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'simple_dom_parser.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

Comment: Did you download the library? Once you have downloaded the php library then add it in the same directory as your php script. I think the library's file name would be simple_html_dom.php so change to require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

Comment: I fixed the require_once() error but it's giving me "Trying to get property of non-object" error